# Why is my sword a fishing rod?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I had to find Nemo in the ocean, so I wandered off to find him for the Angler. I looked at my hot bar for my fishing rod, clicked on a tool with a bait number, and fished with it.

[image]

It was a sword. I got extremely confused, because my Fishing Rod was acting like a sword with no damage, and my sword was acting like a fishing rod.

How do I fix this?

Or why did it happen?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a glitch. Try restarting the game itself; if that doesn't work try restarting your phone, tablet, or mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may have been a glitch that this happened. Sometimes my game glitches out at times for no apparent reason. I hope this helped!