# My Water Bolt acts like a fishing rod for some reason (Terraria Mobile)

Tags: terraria-mobile

After duplicating healing potions I noticed that my water bolt would not work. After getting a worm, a "1" appeared next to it. When I tested it in the ocean it acted like I fishing rod, yet it still made Water Bolt Sounds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my sword a fishing rod?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263920/why-is-my-sword-a-fishing-rod)

Comment: Do you mind including screenshots?

Comment: are you able to catch fish with it, or is it just an ammo bug?

Comment: It has been fixed just wondering why it happened